# geometrical interpretation of equation involving the quadratic form

Tags: quadratic-forms

Please I need help from the experts regarding this question:

Describe the geometrical interpretation of the this equation involving the quadratic form 
$$
(x - \mu)'\,\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu) = c^2
$$

Where x and μ are vectors, x represents your sample vector and μ is the mean
vector. Σ is the variance/covariance matrix and c is a constant.

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [How to ask a homework question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question).

Comment: What kinds of objects are $x,\mu,\Sigma,c$ supposed to be?

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. This is a question I am facing and need help with it. Actually, it ismy first time to get such thing.

Comment: Your comment does not engage with mine. Is $x$ a number? a vector? a triangle? an elephant? what about $\mu$? what about $\Sigma$? and $c$? How can anyone help you, when you won't let us know what you are talking about?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Sorry for my misunderstanding. I edited my question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This is a $p$-dimensional ellipsoid centered at $\mu$. Please see here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsoid#In_general_position
for further details.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. I am looking for how to interpret that and here is a prior template: A quadratic form has the following geometrical interpretation:
 It describes an ellipse whose axes are given by the eigenvectors of  with lengths proportional to the reciprocals of the square roots of the eigenvalues.
 The points on the ellipse are a constant distance from the origin in the n dimensional co-ordinate space. Here A  is positive definite, that can be represented as the sum of its eigenvalues and normalized eigenvectors by spectral decomposition.